# Checking for repeated letters in PHP

Tags: php

I am creating a password validation tool, and one of the requirements I'd like is to prevent the user from having too many letters in a row.  Any letters, including capital letters, cannot be repeated in a sequence of 3 or more times.

My approach has been to move through the password string with a for loop, and embedding a few checks using regex within that.  I can't seem to get the logic to work, and it's probably something simple.  Here is one of my (many) failed attempts at cracking this problem:

```
$seqLetterCounter = 0;
    for($i=0; $i < strlen($password); ++$i) {
            if($password{$i} == '/([a-zA-Z])/') {
                $seqLetterCounter++;
            }
            if($seqLetterCounter > $this->maxSeqLetters){
                $this->errors[6] = 'You have used too many sequential letters in your password.  The maximum allowed is ' . $this->maxSeqLetters . '.';
            }
            if($password{$i} == '/([^a-zA-Z])/') {
                $seqLetterCounter = 0;
            }
        }
```

$password  - a posted value from a form.

$maxSeqLetters - a protected variable that holds an integer value, defined by the user.

errors[] - an array that is used to determine if the password has failed any of the various checks.

Anyone have some pointers?

Comment: Be a good coder, be lazy: http://www.openwall.com/passwdqc/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fairly simple with a regex:

```
if (preg_match('/(\w)\1{2,}/', $password)) {
   die("3+ repeated chars not allowed");
}
```

Search for a character (`\w`), store it (`()`), then see if that same character comes immediately afterwards (`\1`) two or more times `{2,}`.

---

ok... so if consecutive sets of 3+ letters or numbers are out, then try

```
/([a-z]{3,}|[0-9]{3,})/i
```

for the regex instead. Search for any letters (`[a-z]`) OR (`|`) numbers (`[0-9]`), which occur 3 or more times (`{3,}`), and do the match in a case-insensitive manner (`i`), so you don't have to worry about aAa breaking the match.

Comment: That's awesome. Now I'd really want to know more about regexp.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify, as now reading my question I can see why you'd post this answer Marc... I am looking to prevent using ANY letters in a row... i.e. "Dog123" would fail, as would "123Cat".  "Do12Do12" would not fail the check.  Hopefully that clarifies!  I am so happy you answered so quickly though! :DDDDD~

Comment: @Patrick: Please define "letters in a row", can not match your last comment with your question at all. Continue so and I start voting to close because it's not helpful at all.

Comment: Worthwhile to note if you don't care about case (ex: aaA) use the `i` modifier.

Comment: You mean sequential letters/digits, then? acdf and 1357 are ok, but abcd/1234 aren't?

Comment: @hakre Essentially I am trying to prevent repeated use of any letters.  I want the users to split their passwords up by using special characters and numbers, and not make passwords like !Cookie15, which would pass any of my other checks.

Comment: @Wade Your expression didn't seem to change the result, I'm beginning to think it's a syntax error in my original expression.

Comment: @Marc, and Wade, both of your expressions make logical sense - however, dropping both of your expressions into my first if() results in a blank page, so something is breaking.

Comment: blank pages = display_errors is off. Check your server and/or php logs for the error message. and turn ON display_errors while you're developing.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I think I can take it from here!